# Plural reflexives: among themselves

Tags: word-choice, plurals, reflexives

Suppose there are two groups/teams A and B within the same conversational space, and I'm in group A. How would I say:

> - "they (group B) discussed **among themselves**" (as opposed to discussing with group A)
> - "they quarrelled **among themselves**" (as opposed to quarrelling with group A)

I found some candidates here:

- 自分たち (can I just "pluralise" 自分 with たち? Does it work without たち if I want it to reflexively refer to the group instead of an individual?)
- 内輪 (is this readily used conversationally?)
- 自{みずか}ら (I have no idea how to use this at all. Would it be 自らのけんか・自らの相談をする ?)

Sentence construction:

- 彼らは + {自分で・自分たちで・内輪・自ら} + {相談した・けんかした}
- 彼らは + {内輪の・自らの} + {相談・けんか} をした

(I'm not sure what particles work with 内輪 and 自ら)

**Which of the plural reflexives work best? What are the natural ways to convey this meaning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 「～[内]{ない}で」 or 「～の[中]{なか}で」, as in:

> "they (group B) discussed among themselves"
>   「彼らはグループ内で相談/議論した。/ 話し合った。」
>   「彼らはグループの中で相談/議論した。/話し合った。」
>
> "they quarrelled among themselves"
>   「彼らはグループ内で口論/けんかした。/ 口論/けんかになった。/ [揉]{も}めた。」
>   「彼らはグループの中で口論/けんかした。/ 口論/けんかになった。/ 揉めた。」

You could also use 「仲間同士で」「メンバー同士で」:

> 「彼らは仲間同士で/メンバー同士で相談した。/ 揉めた。 etc.」

[内輪]{うちわ} would go better with 揉め(る), as in:

> 「彼らは内輪で揉めた。」
>   「彼らは内輪揉めした。」(← probably a bit colloquial)
>   ("They quarrelled among themselves.")

And I think 自分たちで would go better with 話し合う:

> 「彼らは自分たちで話し合った。」(← probably less formal)
>   ("They discussed among themselves.")